# This pointer suddenly becomes 0x0 in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, null

I have an (apparently) very simple class initialization, with two constructors, and when I want to create a new Friendship, the this pointer of the first argument has the appropriate pointer value, but the second doesn't.

I'll explain better in code - this is one my constructors:

```
Friendship::Friendship(const User &u1, const User &u2){
    *user1 = u1;
    *user2 = u2;
}
```

When I do this in my Test class:

```
bool Test::insertFriendship(User *user1, User *user2) {
    bool friendshipExists = verifyFriendship(user1, user2);

    if(!friendshipExists) {
        friendships.push_back(new Friendship(*user1, *user2)); // this is a ptr_vector container
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the push_back line because apparently the 'this' pointer of the user1 WORKS when it gets to the constructor and it points to a valid memory address, but when it goes to do the user2, the 'this' pointer of user2 points to 0x0 and it fails because that's basically trying to re-deference NULL when it gets to the operator = overload.

Ex: when it tries to create a new Friendship:

this->user1's mem address = 0x100100b20
this->user2's mem address = 0x0 - error!

while

u1's mem address = 0x7fff5fbff900
u2's mem address = 0x7fff5fbff898

I mean, these u1 and u2 mem addresses are valid so why the heck doesn't it work when I try to do:

```
*user1 = u1; //works cos this is 0x100100b20
*user2 = u2; // fails cos this is 0x0 even though u2 is a valid mem address!
```

Anyone know why this strange behavior? Even if I switch user1 and user2 in my push_back, it still won't work at the SECOND one. It's always that pesky second one that never works.

Ah, this is my Friendship header file, nothing too complex.

```
#include "User.h"

#ifndef Friendship_h
#define Friendship_h

class Friendship {
    friend class Test;
protected:
    User *user1;
    User *user2;

public:
    Friendship(const User &u1, const User &u2);
    Friendship(const Friendship &a);
    ~Friendship();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Don't use pointers. Nobody knows how to use pointers right. Guaranteed.

Comment: It works for the first one, and the pointers of my objects are A-ok when I pass them to the constructor, it's the goddamn 'this' pointer (which I can't manipulate to be honest) that's giving me that problem. And it works for the first time, just not the second (and I assume if I had 3 "User" object arguments, only the first one would work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Friendship::Friendship(const User &u1, const User &u2)
{
    *user1 = u1;
    *user2 = u2;
}
```

Since `user1` and `user2` aren't initialized, you cannot dereference them yet. I think you meant:

```
Friendship::Friendship(const User &u1, const User &u2)
{
    user1 = &u1;
    user2 = &u2;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I just had to remove the const in my Friendship because my 'User' copy constructor doesn't use const (it should but then I need to check if a certain 'User' object points to 0x0 and I can't because I can't assign to a new 'User' object if I use const).

Comment: I should have mentioned it in my answer, but using `const` is definitely wrong here. You stash a pointer to these objects through which you can modify them.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a strange error. However, I would suggest something to try first.

Instead of this:

```
Friendship::Friendship(const User &u1, const User &u2)
{
    *user1 = u1;
    *user2 = u2; 
}
```

Do this:

```
Friendship::Friendship(const User *u1, const User *u2)
{
    user1 = u1;
    user2 = u2; 
}
```

and this:

```
bool Test::insertFriendship(User *user1, User *user2) {
    bool friendshipExists = verifyFriendship(user1, user2);

    if(!friendshipExists) {
        friendships.push_back(new Friendship(user1, user2)); // did not dereference user1 and user2, only gave the pointers.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The first form is incorrect. I am surprised it runs at all; `*user1 = u1` Should make a deep copy of u1 and put it into user1. You should explicitly copy the *pointers* into user1: `user1 = u1` where `u1` is a pointer. Hope it helps anyways :).

Comment: Ooh, I actually didn't know that, thanks! So if I do user1 = &u1, like David suggested, that's also okay, right? That's basically giving user1 the mem address of u1. Not to mention it works.

Comment: yes, David's suggestion was dead on, and props to him :) I forgot about that form. It has the advantage of not requiring the '&' sign next to a variable when you're passing it in, if it's not a pointer.

Comment: Don't do this. It changes the meaning of the interface. Now there is the potential for NULL objects to come through the interface. Horrible idea.